# bash (macos) function works in tracing mode but not in normal shell

Tags: bash, macos, function, debugging

I have this bash function in my .bash_profile:

```sh
function tint {
    if [ "$1" == "-a" ]; then
        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
            service="$2"
        fi
    fi
    if [ -z "$service" ]; then
        echo "You must include a service name"
    elif [ -z "$port" ]; then
        if [ "$service" == "aaa" ]; then
            port="8888"
        elif [ "$service" == "bbb" ]; then
            port="3333"
        fi
        sudo telepresence intercept $service --port $port:$port
    fi
}
```

**EDIT**:
Fixed the above code snippet to include only the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

The idea is that you can run any of these and it will work:

```sh
$ tint aaa
$ tint bbb -a
$ tint -a ccc
$ tint aaa 5000
$ tint -a aaa 5000
$ tint bbb -a 5000
$ tint ccc 5000 -a
```

When I try running any of the above commands, I get this output:

```
tint:2: = not found
```

Then when I run it in tracing mode:

```sh
$ bash -x -l
$ tint bbb
```

It totally works without error.

I have no idea why it says "not found" and also no idea why it then works in tracing mode.

Any insights?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really tell me anything more than using tracing mode `bash -x -l` does.

Comment: Okay I'm trying to see if `bashdb` works and gives me something useful.

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash when you're getting errors and not the OS X default shell zsh (Or a basic sh)?

Comment: Have you logged out & back in after the latest change to your .bash_profile? If not, it might be using an old definition of the function. If that's not the problem, try using `set -x` and then run it in your normal shell (rather than starting a new shell with `bash -x -l`). You can use `set +x` to turn tracing off after running it.

Comment: `==` isn't understood by a basic POSIX-only `test`/`[` (Or by zsh's implementation), hence me wondering. Especially since zsh at least gives the same error message you're seeing.

Comment: What does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: @Shawn If he's running `zsh` would it execute `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @Barmar I've seen weirder things than people trying to source bash script files from other shell's startup scripts.

Comment: Oookay yep I was using zsh. Switched to bash and it fixed my issue! @Shawn feel free to submit that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I considered doing so because you appear to have posted a large chunk of mostly irrelevant code you had laying around instead of creating a minimal piece of code that could reproduce your specific problem and posting that. See [ask] and in particular the part about creating/posting a [mcve].

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the insight. I will fix the code snippets to make them more minimal for the benefit of future viewers.
I guess it's just kind of confusing because I've seen plenty of questions asked where the asker includes very little information which makes it hard for people to adequately answer them. But I guess it's a balance.

Comment: You're welcome, just make sure not to make them incomplete when making them minimal. The [mcve] code should always simply be the smallest possible complete script you can come up with that we can run to demonstrate just the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the question, the answer is that I needed to be using a bash session, but was in fact using a zsh session.

Figured this out thanks to @Barmar by running `echo $SHELL`

As @Shawn mentioned:

> == isn't understood by a basic POSIX-only test/[ (Or by zsh's implementation)

Running `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change from zsh to bash fixed it, and then I had to reopen the terminal for it to actually take effect (this may not be necessary for everyone, but at least for me using Hyper as my terminal emulator, the change didn't take effect until closing and reopening the app).